# switch store without GET Parameter in Magento

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I would like to make an invisible redirection from a store to a different one (I set up multistore)
into my module, for now I'm using this snippet but it shows GET parameter:

```
echo '<p><a href="' . Mage::getUrl() . '?___store=' . $store . '">pick up this restaurant</a></p>'
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a POST form means that when using the back button customers might encounter an annoying "This page needs to be refreshed" message in their browser. Another way would be to redirect from `www.example.com/?___store=1` to `www.example.com` during some early event, say, during controller pre-dispatch. Only redirect if there is a `___store` parameter.

A better way would be to have different domains for each store. That avoids the `___store` parameter altogether and provides definite feedback to the customer that they are on the correct site.

Comment: It's true that the "needs to be refresh" message can be annoying, I'm gonna try you're solution,do you know in which file is located the controller pre-dispatch ? Concerning the multiwebsite solution, i just have one domain name, but I will perhaps change my configuration from multistore to multiwebsite, do this config switch may interfer with my current problem here ?

Comment: There are many controllers, you cannot alter them all, so listen to the event [`controller_action_predispatch`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events) which occurs for all controllers on all pages. You will need to [write an observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) for that.

Comment: You can add different domains - or just sub-domains - to multistores without changing to a multiwebsite setup. They're all configured in the same way.

Comment: I accept your answer even if I switch to another project right now, but it s gonna come back!

Answer (score 10):

You have to set `COOKIE` for the store

For example :

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeViewId);
Mage::app()->getCookie()->set(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME, 'de', TRUE);

de = Store code.
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Just to recap, you only need two lines of code to switch stores:
`Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeViewId);
            Mage::app()->getCookie()->set(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME, $storeViewCode, TRUE);`

Comment: Also, regarding a comment by the OP saying he's "gonna try a more server side solution", I'm pretty sure these are server side cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use forms (method post), and acording to the processed data, set the store: `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(store_id)`

Comment: That's what I had in mind , submit a form with the store_id as a POST value, change store via magento function setCurrentStore and redirect to the homepage but I can't make it work yet, I gonna try again and will come back here, thx for suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the store code in a cookie and have your index.php check to see if the cookie exists or not, if it does then it load up the store by its code, if not show default store.

Answer (score 1):

Add store code to urls you can enable this from admin page

Comment: I don't want to display the code store in the URL (even if it s not a GET parameter), cause the full website must look like an unique store, it has to be transparent for the user, was a good idea though